# JSON markup - SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Tags: json

I'm getting one error in my code, Please suggest.

Google tool gives:

```
Syntax error: value, object or array expected.
```

[image]

JASON=LD Playground gives:

```
JSON markup - SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

The latter error is due the fact that you left some HTML part inside the JSON validator text box (`<script...` is an HTML tag, it's not part of JSON).

The former error is due the fact that sometimes your JSON is using wrong double quotes symbols. Please note that double quotes can appear as:

```
"   U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
“   U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
”   U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
```

**Only the first symbol** (that is the one that is present in almost all keyboards) is valid in JSON.

Comment: thank you Enrico ! but can not find where it is.I copy and paste the tag, just change the values.

Comment: `name`, `alternateName` and others has wrong quotation marks. If you look at the quotation mark symbols in your JSON you will notice the difference